# Change color of angular datepicker material component

Tags: css, angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am working on a angular material datepicker which will be on a black background. How do I change change the default color of the datepicker's icon, underline and placeholder text to all white color?

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="picker" matSuffix></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Use your browser debugger to find the class name of desired element. After you get the class name, you can use it to change the color. You might have to use ::ng-deep as well

Comment: `::ng-deep` is on the radar to be deprecated: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 16):

You can use ::ng-deep. Here is the working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-datepicker-qj73og

```
::ng-deep .mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
 /*change color of label*/
 color: white !important;
}

::ng-deep.mat-form-field-underline {
 /*change color of underline*/
 background-color: white !important;
} 

::ng-deep.mat-form-field-ripple {
 /*change color of underline when focused*/
 background-color: white !important;;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label {
 /*change color of label*/
 color: white !important;
}


mat-datepicker-toggle {
 color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: This helped me however, I did not need to add `::ng-deep`. I removed that and it worked for me.

Comment: you don't need to put it in ::ng-deep if you put it in styles.css / scss, you can do ` .mat-form-field-appearance-outline mat-datepicker-toggle` to make it a global style that only applies for date pickers within a mat form field of appearance outline

Comment: At the component level, I did need ::ng-deep, however, you can just nest everything in ::ng-deep { }, if you want to DRY it up a bit. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just follow this guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#theming-only-certain-components.

You can do something like (in some scss theme file:

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

// Just include this next line once in your application, so if you are building
// a file just to theme the datepicker, don't put it here.
@include mat-core();

// Define the datepicker theme.
$datepicker-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$datepicker-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$datepicker-theme:   mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent);

// Apply the theme to your component
@include mat-datepicker-theme($datepicker-theme);
```

Comment: Although the theme approach is complicated (it required plenty of Googling on my part to understand it and get it working), this is likely the best future-proof way since Angular claims  they could change class names, etc. in future versions of Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Use `::ng-deep` and select those element:

[See working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p91rwg?file=app/datepicker-value-example.css)

```
::ng-deep datepicker-value-example .mat-form-field-label{
   color:red;
}

::ng-deep .mat-datepicker-toggle{
   color:red;
}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline{
background: red;
}
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Answer (score 1):

To set font color above answers didn't work for me. I used following, hope this helps to someone.

**To change color**

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell-content, .mat-date-range-input-separator {
  color: blue;
}
```

**To change font size and weight**

```
.mat-calendar-body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Add this to `styles.css`, I'm using `Angular 12` and `Angular Material 12`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Angular Material 14 and this works fine for me:

```
<mat-form-field class="w-100" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
    <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY – MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

style.scss:

```
.mat-form-field-type-mat-date-range-input .mat-hint {
  color: white !important;
}

.mat-form-field-flex {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.mat-date-range-input-inner {
  color: black !important;
}
```

Before adding styles:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]